# How this particular raster array form an 'F'

Tags: c++, opengl

This particular array

```
GLubyte rasters[24] = {
   0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
   0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
   0xff, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xc0};
```

combined with this code

```
glBitmap (10, 12, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, rasters);
```

forms an 'F' I am not able to understand the array?

Answer (score 2):

You are plotting a bitmap, that is a "map of bits".

If you convert those values to binary, and write them in a 16-bit matrix you will get:

```
1100 0000 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000
1111 1111 0000 0000
1111 1111 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000
1100 0000 0000 0000 
1111 1111 1100 0000
1111 1111 1100 0000
```

And as you can see the "1" form an F.

**EDIT**: As @benjymous pointed out in the comments, the F is upside down because OpenGL uses the lower-left corner as origin.

Comment: GL uses an origin at the bottom left, rather than the top left, so if you consider those rows being drawn in sequence from bottom to top, the F will end up the right way up

Comment: GL always uses lower-left corner as starting point. Not just bitmap (noone uses it anyway), but everywhere.

Comment: Yes I agree with Benjymous its actually from the Bottom left rather than top-lef

Comment: is there any predefined list of array representing these characters. any pdf or some sort

Comment: @SiddharthTaunk you want to draw a text in that way? This is a really bad idea - slowest thing ever, and `glBitmap` no longer exists starting with, as i recall, GL 3.0

Comment: @SiddharthTaunk It's more fun, and pretty good practice of binary and hex comprehension, to design your own.

Comment: @keltar: Only it uses upper left for origin when it doesn't use the lower left for origin. Like in cube map images.

Comment: @datenwolf cube map uses standard GL's 3D coordinates, so it originates from center of cube. There is no left-top here - nor could i remember there are anywhere else; more examples maybe?

Comment: @keltar: I'm talking about the cube map image specification i.e. the directions in which pixels of each face are indexed. If you look at how cube maps are implemented, the direction vector is first used to determine which of the 6 faces to use. Then the 2D texture coordinate on the face is determined. When cube maps got introduced, the specification was written to follow the *RenderMan* specification, which put the origin of the cube face images each in the upper left. It's really a ridiculous thing to have this inconsistency in OpenGL, but that's what we have now.

Comment: @datenwolf erm.. sorry, i don't get it. Doesn't first texel in texel array (passed to `TexImage2D`) still match the bottom-left of specified cube map side?

Comment: @benjymous: thanks, I assumed there was something like that, I updated the answer.

Comment: @keltar: Technically at the moment of passing data to `glTexImage2D` there is no such thing as a geometrical origin. There es a begin of data, and that's it. The actual meaning of direction only gets applied in the vertex setup stage, when places on the screen are determined. Anyway, the notion of OpenGL is that texture coordinate (0,0) is at the wrap between the first and last pixel of the image data. Up/Down/Left/Right is a rasterization thing. And in cube maps the direction of up/down is flipped to the regular expectation. If you really want to get into the details: Read the specification.